# How to store fetched data in state and render it in my component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have fetched the array using the `graphql` query and stored it in a variable called `mpbrands`. Now I want to store it in the state and render it in my component. I tried the below but its not giving any response

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        }
    }     
async componentDidMount(){
        let brandQuery = BrandPageInstance.getBrandList();
        await fetchQuery(brandQuery).then((mpbrand) => {
                this.setState({
                    count: mpbrand.items
                })
                console.log(count)
            },
            (error) => console.log(error)
        )   
    }
```

In the console I am getting an error `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: count is not defined` . My array structure is

```
mpbrand:
     items: Array(10)
             0: {default_value: "CHEVROLET", image: "image_url"}
```

Let me know how to do it. Since I am newbie not able to store it in the `state`

Comment: error is because of  `console.log(count)` statement. there is not variable called count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `console.log(this.state.count)` That should solve the reference error.

count is part of the state object. So you can access it via `this.state.count`.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all `count` is not your **state**. It's the property `state`.
- Secondly, replacing `console.log(count)` with `console.log(this.state.count)` won't work (in the essence that you won't see count updated) since your new state will only be available to you in next **render**.

But `setState` provides a second **callback** where you can access the updated state like so :-

```
  this.setState({
    count: mpbrand.items
    },()=>console.log(this.state.count))
```